# Changing SFMC Connector from one Sales cloud to another

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, marketingcloudapi

Is this possible? How hard would it be to move a client with an exisiting Marketing Cloud to connect it to a different Salesforce org (they are moving to a new org for core CRM, but have marketing cloud linked to their old org).

Answer (score 3):

This is a very broad question and impossible to answer with the input you've given. To make it short: the complexity of disconnecting and reconnecting depends on the current connector setup (integration architecture) and the complexity of campaigns and other processes running in the SFMC account.

A few points from the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_co_disconnect_account.htm&type=5):

> Disconnecting does the following:
>
> - Removes the connection between your Marketing Cloud account and Sales or Service Cloud org.
> - Removes the Salesforce system user’s credentials and resets the connection at the account level.
> - Removes user mappings in the disconnected business unit and synchronized data extensions.
> - Cancels tracking subscriptions. Any tracking for previous sends is not pushed to the previous Sales or Service Cloud org. Tracking is not
>   affected in the Marketing Cloud.
>
> If a new connection is made, tracking for previous sends is not pushed
> to the new org.

Given above, disconnecting from an existing account would impact all the journeys, automations, triggered sends and all other processes that use Salesforce data, and upon connecting to a new org, you would be looking at reconfiguring everything from scratch.